# changer helper id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, helper

i want to change helper id it doesent work

```
$('.column1').draggable({
containment: '#sort' , 
helper:'clone',
connectToSortable:'#sort',
start: function(event,ui) {
            i=counts[ 0 ]++;
            document.getElementById('wid').value=i;
            updateCounterStatus( $start_counter, counts[ 0 ] );
            ui.helper.attr("id","colum2");


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the jQuery UI documentation, that should work...how do you know it is not working? All I can suggest is to try changing `ui.helper.attr("id", "colum2");` to `$(ui.helper).attr("id", "colum2");`.

Comment: it work but it change id of original and clone the goal is changing id of clone only – user653826 0 secs

Answer (score 0):

Helper ID can only be either 'original' or 'clone'. If you change it, it will stop working.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: True. I guess he wants the code to run only once? JQuery has a nice function for that @user653826. .one() http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: what im doing is draggable sortable column so what i want to do is changing id of clone that i dragged

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery draggable helper has the class 'ui-draggable-dragging'. Try this:

```
start: function(event,ui) {
    i=counts[ 0 ]++;
    document.getElementById('wid').value=i;
    updateCounterStatus( $start_counter, counts[ 0 ] );
    $('.ui-draggable-dragging').attr("id","colum2");
}
```

Comment: that work but the problem that it change the original one id too

Answer (score 0):

well i made it thanks for your answer

solution:

```
$('#colum').draggable({

helper:'clone',
connectToSortable:'#sort',
start: function(event,ui) {
            k=counts[ 0 ]++;
            document.getElementById('wid').value=i;
            updateCounterStatus( $start_counter, counts[ 0 ] );
             $(this).attr("id","colum"+k);



        }
```